# ToolchainResolution picking up toolchain for the wrong platform

Tags: bazel

I defined a new rust toolchain as follows (forked from https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_rust):

```
toolchain(
    name = "toolchain_for_armv7-linux-androideabi",
    exec_compatible_with = ["@platforms//cpu:x86_64", "@platforms//os:windows"],
    target_compatible_with = ["@platforms//cpu:armv7", "@platforms//os:android"],
    toolchain = "@rust_windows_x86_64//:toolchain_for_armv7-linux-androideabi_impl",
    toolchain_type = "@rules_rust//rust:toolchain",
)
```

There is also an existing toolchain defined like this:

```
toolchain(
    name = "toolchain_for_x86_64-apple-darwin",
    exec_compatible_with = ["@platforms//cpu:x86_64", "@platforms//os:osx"],
    target_compatible_with = ["@platforms//cpu:x86_64", "@platforms//os:osx"],
    toolchain = "@rust_darwin_x86_64//:toolchain_for_x86_64-apple-darwin_impl",
    toolchain_type = "@rules_rust//rust:toolchain",
)
```

And building a target for that platform:

`bazel build --toolchain_resolution_debug=@rules_rust//rust:toolchain --experimental_platforms_api vrst-test/android --platforms=//platforms:android_armv7`

Here is a snippet of ToolchainResolution debug info:

```
INFO: ToolchainResolution:   Type @rules_rust//rust:toolchain: target platform @local_config_platform//:host: execution @local_config_platform//:host: Selected toolchain @rust_darwin_x86_64//:toolchain_for_x86_64-apple-darwin_impl
INFO: ToolchainResolution:     Type @rules_rust//rust:toolchain: target platform @local_config_platform//:host: Rejected toolchain @rust_darwin_x86_64//:toolchain_for_armv7-linux-androideabi_impl; mismatching values: armv7, android
```

For some reason, target platform is `@local_config_platform//:host` despite me explicitly specifying the platform as android_armv7, which is defined as follows:

````
platform(
    name = "android_armv7",
    constraint_values = [
      "@platforms//cpu:armv7",
      "@platforms//os:android",
    ],
)```
````

Comment: Which target is that part of the debug info for? I suspect it's something being built for the host, which means the target is the host for that part of the build. Is there another section of toolchain resolution info with the target platform as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Bazel resolves toolchains both for the target platforms, specified by `--platforms`, and the [host](https://bazel.build/docs/build#build-config-cross-compilation) platform, specified by `--host_platform`. If you actually want host tools to be built for `toolchain_for_armv7-linux-androideabi`, you will want to set `--host_platform`.

Comment: No, I am trying to build for Android/armv7.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question was asked one years ago, I tried to answer and hope it helps.

From bazel documentation: https://bazel.build/extending/toolchains#toolchain-resolution

> A target_compatible_with or exec_compatible_with clause matches a
> platform if, for each constraint_value in its list, the platform also
> has that constraint_value (either explicitly or as a default).

And:

> For each available execution platform, you associate each toolchain
> type with the first available toolchain, if any, that is compatible
> with this execution platform and the target platform.

Hence, your toolchain is not compatible with your execution platform, which is @local_config_platform//:host

This platform, @local_config_platform//:host, is generated by bazel automatically and it varies for different systems. Hence, to ensure your toolchain is selected, you need to:

1. ensure your toolchain is compatible with execution platform. You can check it by issue `bazel query @local_config_platform//:host --output=build`.
2. specify your target platform explictly by specifying it on command line : `--platforms=//label/to/your/toolchain:toolchain_name`